# Using Nodejs to render html-css-javascript-images

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, webserver

I'm exploring and testing nodejs with a html, css and javascript.

When i run index.html locally (no webserver) I can see the css,js,html,images render properly on my browser.

The problem when I create server.js and browse localhost:8000/index.html, it just return my heading and paragraph... no nice images, css, js execute...
I have gone through from SO and due to calling is only on html file but not css/js/images.

I don't know what's the problem, and how to proceed further.

This is my `server.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var connect = require('connect');
var http = require('http');

var path = "";

var app = connect().use(express.static(__dirname + path));
http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

This is my `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST NODEJS WEB</title>
    <!-- library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/xero/next/css/next.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/home/xero/next/js/next.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/xero/next/font- 
    awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topology-container"></div>
    <!-- Application scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="topology_data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="action-panel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="topology.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is folder structure in my machine:

```
home
  xero
    next
      js/next.min.js
      css/next.min.css
    myweb
      index.html
      topology_data.js
      action-panel.js
      topology.js
      main.js
      server.js
```

When i browse index.html..only can see 'My First Heading' and 'My first paragraph.'

Please help and advise me further. Thank you.
***Thanks to all***

Comment: Whats error in browser console?

Comment: I don't see any code in your `server.js` which handles any incoming request, So how you are gonna get the HTML file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to create api for sending the css and javascript file from Node server. Since you are already using the `express` you don't need to use connect and http to start a server. Using express you can run a server, check the code

`

```
var app = express();
app.listen(8000,  function() {
    console.log('app listening on port 8000!');
});
```

`

In order to send `next.min.css` and `next.min.js` files just create the get api in your server

`

```
app.get('/script', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile("/home/xero/next/js/next.min.js");
});
```

`

`

```
app.get('/css', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("/home/xero/next/css/next.min.css");
});
```

`

and call these apis from your `index.html` file.

`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8000/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8000/script">
```

`

Check out the whole working solution -

https://codesharehub.com/post/e6b58ce0dab274f977af2fd7a855008ff6034ffc

Comment: I getting error when run node server.js app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, path)));
                            ^

TypeError: path.join is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xero/next/server.js:20:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3

Comment: Any simple way to do it... ?

Comment: Updated the code, checkout the link https://codesharehub.com/post/e6b58ce0dab274f977af2fd7a855008ff6034ffc

Comment: That is the simplest way, it will work give it a try and I am here to help you, no worries.

Comment: Im getting more error sir... path.js:28
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received { resolve: [Function: resolve],
  normalize: [Function: normalize],
  isAbsolute: [Function: isAbsolute],
  join: [Function: join],
  relative: [Function: relative],
  _makeLong: [Function: _makeLong],
  dirname: [Function: dirname],
  basename: [Function: basename],
  extname: [Function: extname],
  format: [Function: format],
  parse: [Function: parse],

Comment: It works now...but the menu icon/image does not visualize properly.... I have test it locally without webserver and all the menu icons can be render nicely...

Comment: I guess you are using the font-awesome.min.css for icons right?

Comment: Yes...ok...typo of my font file... after change it ok... my questions (1) If i have multiple js file to be used..how can do it with this solution? (2) for example  font-awesome.min.css...how to add this to server.js?

Comment: You can do it by dynamically providing the path to files like below

Comment: app.get('/script/:pathToFile', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile("/home/xero/next/js/" + req.params.pathToFile);
});

Comment: updated the solution for dynamic files, checkout https://codesharehub.com/post/e6b58ce0dab274f977af2fd7a855008ff6034ffc

Comment: If it helps pls like my post https://codesharehub.com/post/e6b58ce0dab274f977af2fd7a855008ff6034ffc on https://codesharehub.com

Comment: I tried above...not working...do i need to comment app.get('/script', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile("/home/xero/next/js/next.min.js");?

Comment: Yeah if u want to use the dynamic solution u can comment the above get api and use the api that is dynamically sending the javascript file.

Comment: I really appreciated your time and support on this...thank you sir.

Comment: Thanks Chenoi and you are welcome to share your projects and code on https://codesharehub.com. You can create your resume and add your projects along with it for free.

Comment: @chenoi or just use a one-liner `app.use(express.static("../next"))` without any huzzles.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a server to serve html. The links in the html are relative with the base of the server.

i.e

your server is running on `/home/xero/myweb`

So, your links in css or js becomes `/home/xero/myweb/home/xero/next/css/next.min.css`,
**Which doesn't exists**

As, you can't access parent directory of your server base directory.

**Use following Directory Structure**

```
home
  xero
    myweb
      next
        js/next.min.js
        css/next.min.css
      index.html
      topology_data.js
      action-panel.js
      topology.js
      main.js
      server.js
```

And, then in index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST NODEJS WEB</title>
    <!-- library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/next/css/next.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/next/js/next.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/next/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="topology-container"></div>
    <!-- Application scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="topology_data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="action-panel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="topology.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

***Edit**

Use `app.use(express.static(<path>))`. [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) is the documentation.

code:

```
var express = require("express");
var connect = require("connect");
var http = require("http");

var path = "";

var app = connect().use(express.static(__dirname + path));

app.use(express.static("../next/"));

http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
```

Ans now in html you just need to refer as
`css/next.min.css` and `js/next.min.js`

Comment: Hi sir...thank you....but is it possible I can maintain my directory structure..? If I maintain the structure...where should I add/edit in server.js

Comment: If I can maintain the dir structure and do something to server.js so that it can refer to css and js folder

Comment: @chenoi Added Solution! :p and tick the answer if it works!